# JQuery drop down with position absolute bottom

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a `slideToggle` effect in JQuery.
I have a div which is positioned as:

```css
someDiv {
   position : absolute;
   bottom : 100px; 
}
```

Now when the function ( `$("#someDiv").slideToggle();` ) is triggered on click, the `div` slides UP from bottom rather than showing or dropping down.

I want it to drop normally form TOP while it is positioned as above. How do I do that? I have read that positioning from bottom gives it that effect but could not find a solution anywhere.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Tx2xx/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function in combination with the window `resize` event to dynamically position the div 100px from the bottom using the CSS `top` property so that the `slideToggle()` acts the way you want like this:

**CSS**

```css
#theDiv {
  position : absolute;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<button>Toggle</button>
<div id="theDiv">...<div>​
```

**JS**

```
// Positions Div From Bottom //
function positionDiv($target, fromBottom){
    $target.css({
        top: $(window).height() - fromBottom
    });
}

// Bind positionDiv() to Window Resize and Trigger at Start //
$(window).resize(function(){
    positionDiv($('#theDiv'), 100);
}).trigger('resize');

// Bind Toggle to Button //
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('#theDiv').slideToggle();
});​
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/B5dGq/2/)**

I hope this helps!

Comment: Just the thing i needed...the window.resize() thing did not strike me!! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

What about this?
http://jsfiddle.net/fZGGG/6/